# How to fix text color error in creating express route

Tags: javascript, client-server

I am required to create an express route that handles a HTTP GET request for the path /color.html where it responds with a valid webpage containing a level 1 heading reading either red, yellow, green or blue iteratively. The color of the heading text should match the text. eg. first visit reads 'red', second visit reads 'yellow' and so on. 
Yet I keep getting this error which I do not know how to fix. Here's my code and the error:

Code:

```
var colourText =["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"];
colourText[0].style.color = "red";
colourText[1].style.color = "yellow";
colourText[2].style.color = "green";
colourText[3].style.color = "blue";
var i = 0;

router.get('/color.html', function(req, res, next) {
res.send(
'<DOCTYPE!=html> \
<html> \
    <head> \
    <title></title> \
    </head> \
    <body><h1>'+colourText[i]+'</h1></body> \
</html>');
i++;
if (i==4){
    i = 0;
}
});
```

Error:

```
/home/ubuntu/wdc/prac4/routes/index.js:17
colourText.style.color = 'red';
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/wdc/prac4/routes/index.js:17:24)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/wdc/prac4/app.js:6:19)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prac4@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the prac4@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2020-03-30T05_18_04_474Z-debug.log
```

Sorry Im super new to this. Any sort of help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `colourText` is an array of strings, those strings don't have `style` property.

Comment: You’re iterating over an array of strings, but you seem to be treating it like an array of DOM Nodes. “red” does not have a “style” property, so “red”.style returns undefined. undefined does not have a “color” property, and so you can’t read the property “color” of undefined.